Chrome Devtools dropping the frame rate of REACT app
I am using electron version 23.0.0 with node 21.7.1. I have React version of 18.2.0. I am working with a redux based REACT app and I was facing issues of the app lagging when I was changing the inputs of controlled input components. The app is very jerky while controlling the input and we can visually see frame drops whenever we do simple slider controlled visual changes in the app
I cleaned up the code to make it more performant and the REACT profiler also shows good performance. I came to read somewhere that closing the devtools will solve this issue.... and guess what? It actually does!
Now problem is that I do want to keep the devtools opened for developing and it just doesnt seem right that the devtools itself is causing problems. Can anyone please tell why devtools can cause such problems and how to solve them while keeping the devtools opened?
